# Iterate over nodes with XSLT and get attributes value

Tags: xml, xslt, hyperlink

I have an XML file with a structure like below:

```
<entries>
  <entry>
    <sense>
      <definition>
        <RegDef>
           <w ID="1">word1</w><w ID="2">word2</w>
        </RegDef>
     </definition>
    </sense>
   </entry>
  <entry>
    <sense>
      <definition>
        <RegDef>
           <w ID="12">word3</w><w ID="43">word4</w><w ID="413">word5</w>
        </RegDef>
     </definition>
    </sense>
   </entry>
.
.
.
</entries>
```

I want to iterate over each  node and get the value of attribute ID and display it like a hyperlink.

I tried

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="entries/entry">
  <html>
   <a href="{concat('http://example.com/show.php?id=', entries/entry/list/sense/definition/w[@ID='0'])}">word</a>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it doesn't get me any ID. I want the value of each attribute ID to concatenate it at the url, and then put in the  tag the word that has the attribute concatenated at the url.

I want the output to be : the values [word1](http://example.com/show.php?id=1)   and [word2](http://example.com/show.php?id=2) like hyperlink, and I want each hyperlink to have the attribute the same with the attribute on the node word1 and word2

Answer (score 1):

Below for-each loop might get you started;

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="entries/entry/sense/definition/RegDef">
        <xsl:for-each select="w">
            <html>
                <a href="{concat('http://example.com/show.php?id=', @ID)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </a>
            </html>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is working but my actual XML structure is a little different. I have another node <definition>   (<definition><Morf></Morf><RegDef><w></w></RegDef></definition>). When i run the example with the <Morf> node it's returning me an error: "This page contains the following errors:

error on line 5 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document"...